# If $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a Brownian motion and $\tau$ is a stopping time, then the stopped process $(B_{\min(\tau,t)})_{t\ge 0}$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname{P})$. By definition $B_t$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $t$.

Now, let $\mathbb F=(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $\tau$ be a $\mathbb F$-stopping time. Is the *stopped process* $B^\tau:=(B_{\min(\tau,t)})_{t\ge 0}$ integrable, i.e. does it hold $$B_{\min(\tau,t)}\in\mathcal{L}^1(\operatorname{P})\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\;?\tag{1}$$

I assume, that $(1)$ can be easily shown and most likely $B_{\min(\tau,t)}$ is normally distributed, too. However, how can we prove that?

Maybe we need boundedness of $\tau$. Then, there exists a $T>0$ such that $$B_{\min(\tau,t)}=B_T\;\;\;\text{for all }t>T$$ and $B_{\min(\tau,t)}$ would be normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $T$ for all $t>T$.

But that is not exactly the desired statement $(1)$.

---

Remark: $\;\;\;$ $B$ is called *Brownian motion* $:\Leftrightarrow$ $B$ is a real-valued stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname{P})$ with

- $B_0=0$ almost surely
- $B$ has independent and stationary increments
- $B_t\;\tilde\;\mathcal{N}_{0,\;t}$
- $B$ is almost surely continuous

Please note, that out there exists a definition of a so-called *$\mathbb{G}$-Brownian motion*, where $\mathbb{G}$ is a given filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$. One can show, that the Brownian motion defined above is a $\mathbb{G}$-Brownian motion, if $G$ satisfies the *usual conditions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doob says: $B_{\tau \wedge t} = E[B_{t \wedge t}\mid \mathcal{F}_\tau]$.

Jensen says: 
$$E[\lvert B_{\tau \wedge t}  \rvert] = E[\lvert E[B_{t \wedge t}\mid \mathcal{F}_\tau]\rvert] \leq E[ E[\lvert B_{t \wedge t}\rvert\mid \mathcal{F}_\tau]] = E[\lvert B_t \rvert] < \infty$$

Comment: Could you give a reference for that what Doob says?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Sure. Theorem 3.6 in the following lecture notes. http://www.math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/courses/735/notes.pdf

Comment: I don't think, that e can assume, that $B$ is a $\mathbb{F}$-martingale. So, I think that we need to use a filtration such that $B$ is a martingale with respect to that filtration.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Well in your problem statement you should mention the filtration with respect to which $B$ is a Brownian motion. What is the reason for considering two different filtrations, one for BM one for $\tau$?

Comment: And just to make sure, that I don't lead myself into a wrong direction: "Integrability of a process does not imply integrability of a corresponding stopped process. You've used, that we've got a martingale and a stopping time with respect to the same filtration", right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes I only considered one filtration which gave meaning to both BM and the stopping time.

Comment: Ah, I see. Please take note of my latest edit. Can we say, that $\left(B_{\min(\tau,t)}\right)_{t\ge 0}$ is integrable, only if $B$ is a $\mathbb{F}$-martingale and $\tau$ a $\mathbb{F}$-stopping time?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Well that would be a bold statement (the only if part). If I come up with something, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer to this once one knows the density of the signed running minimum/maximum of a reflected Brownian motion,
$$M_t^{\pm} = \sup_{0 < s < t}\pm B_s \lor 0.$$
Clearly 
$$|B_{\tau \land t}| \leq M_t^+ + M_t^-$$ almost surely. In fact, for each
$t,$ $M_t^\pm \overset{d}{=} |B_t|.$ (See Karatzas and Shreve, for instance). 
Then 
$$E|B_{\tau \land t}| \leq EM_t^+ + EM_t^- < \infty.$$